# I did not understand what is happening in my code

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

This is my code. I want to **reverse my number in array1**. And i was except this programming given **100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10**. But my Programm was showing this result:  **100,90,80,70,60,70,80,90,100.** I don't know really why this code showing that result. I did not understand what is happening in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ara1[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
    int temp,i,j;
    for(i=0,j=9;i<10;i++,j--)
    {
        temp=ara1[j];
        ara1[i]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",ara1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'I did not understand what is happening in my code.' - that is why debuggers were invented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First iteration in the loop you swap element `0` and `9`, right? Then you swap element `1` and `8`, `2` and `7`, `3` and `6`, `4` and `5`. With me this far?

Then the loop continues to swap element `5` and `4`, which you just swapped once, and then `6` and `3`, `7` and `2`, `8` and `1` and finally `9` and `0`.

If you stop the loop halfway it will work. Of course when I say "swap" I am liberal, because as noted by lkrabbe you don't actually *swap* the elements. You need to do e.g

```
temp = ara1[j];
ara1[j] = ara1[i];
ara1[i] = temp;
```

Both of the above problems would have been *very* obvious if you had tried to step through the code in a debugger, so the lesson here is not how to fix the loop, but to learn how to use a debugger to find out these things yourself.

Comment: good to mention a debugger here. Of course a simple printf debugging would be perfect here too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i will check this code with debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Your swap term

```
temp = ara1[j];
ara1[i] = temp;
```

can be reduced to

```
ara1[j] = ara1[i];
```

but you want to swap, so you should

```
temp = ara1[j];
ara1[j] = ara1[i];
ara1[i] = temp;
```

or better define a swap expression

```
#define SWAP(a,b) do {
    int __temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = __temp;
} while(0)
```

and use

```
SWAP(ara1[i],ara1[j]);
```

Comment: I am new in Programming. I dont know swap expression.  I used your code in baic c, but one problem that programm show this result: 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 but i want to this number 100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10

Comment: @asad see joachims solution. You should only loop halfway.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0,j=9;i<5;i++,j--) {
   temp=ara1[i];
   ara1[i]=ara1[j];
   ara1[j]=temp;

}
```

That will do. The problem is you actually arent swaping any alements you are just copying the last one into the first one and so on.

EDITED: now it works.

Comment: but it was showing 10,20,30,40......100 but i want to this result 100,90,...30,20,10

Comment: You loop variables that depend on each other: `j = L - i - 1`, then `for (i=0; i<L/2; ++i) { j = L-i-1; ...`, where `L = sizeof(ara1) / sizeof(int)`, to get your parameters right.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the loop problem
after 5 iterations the values of 10,20,30,40,50 are lost due to override you have to preserve them in the `j` positions

Try like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ara1[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
    int temp,i,j;
    for(i=0,j=9;i<10/2;i++,j--)
    {
        temp=ara1[j];
        ara1[j]=ara1[i]; // this is the change i have made
        ara1[i]=temp;    
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",ara1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is how the array looks after 5 iterations we lost `10 to 50` values

`10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
100,90,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
100,90,80,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
100,90,80,70,50,60,70,80,90,100
100,90,80,70,60,60,70,80,90,100`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work as you expect with single array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int ara1[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
        int temp,i,j;
        for(i=0,j=9;i<5;i++,j--)
        {
                temp=ara1[j];
                ara1[j]=ara1[i];
                ara1[i] = temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
                printf("%d\n",ara1[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the variable tmp actually has not been used. You just put 100 in arra1[0],90 inarra1[1]......

Comment: Please, what do you want to express?